# How to handle "not found" ticker in yfinance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance, yfinance

So im trying to fetch some stock data in a loop (not sure if i can pass an array), like this:

```
def getData(ticker):
    print (ticker)
    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start_date, end=today)
    dataname= ticker+'_'+str(today)
    files.append(dataname)
    SaveData(data, dataname)
```

But for some reasons, some of the tickers i feed to `pdr.get_data_yahoo()` are not found, and python throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py", line 157, in _read_one_data
    data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
KeyError: 'HistoricalPriceStore'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "borsdata_api.py", line 65, in <module>
    getData(row['ticker'])
  File "borsdata_api.py", line 47, in getData
    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start_date, end=today)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 82, in get_data_yahoo
    return YahooDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 251, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py", line 160, in _read_one_data
    raise RemoteDataError(msg.format(symbol, self.__class__.__name__))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: No data fetched for symbol ADDV-TO-1.ST using YahooDailyReader
```

Is it possible to just skip this iteration and move on the next one in the list?

Comment: You can use `try/except` blocks...

Answer (score -2):

```
def getData(ticker):
    print (ticker)
    try:
        data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start_date, end=today)
        dataname= ticker+'_'+str(today)
        files.append(dataname)
        SaveData(data, dataname)
    except:
        pass #or traceback.print_exc(), or traceback.format_exc()
        #print_exc() will raise the error and print traceback.
        #format_exc() will return the error as a string.
```